# Negative binomial distribution & Bernoulli distribution - expected value, MGF

Tags: self-study, negative-binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution, moment-generating-function

could anyone please help me with the following exercise?

Let us assume that the random variable $N$ has a negative binomial distribution $P(N=n) = (n+1)(\frac{3}{4})^2(\frac{1}{4})^n$. $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are independent, identically distributed random variables. Each $X_i$ has Bernoulli distribution where $P(X=1) = p$ and $P(X=0) = q$.

We also introduce following random variables: $N_1 = \sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i $ if $N>0$ and $N_0 = N - N_1$.
What we have to calculate is $E[\frac{N_1}{N_0+1}]$.

So my idea how to deal with this exercise was to use moment generating functions and somehow derive from that distribution of $N_1$ - I was hoping to get another negative binomial distribution.
$$
MGF(N) = (\frac{\frac{3}{4}}{1-\frac{1}{4}e^t})^n
$$
$$
MGF(X) = 1 - p + pe^t
$$
so:
$$
MGF(N_1) = (\frac{\frac{3}{4}}{1-\frac{1}{4}(q+pe^t)})^n
$$
I tried transforming this equations somehow and managed to obtain:
$$
MGF(N_1) = (\frac{\frac{3}{4-q}}{1-\frac{p}{4-q}e^t})
$$
which is another negative binomial distribution. I assume that since $N_0 = N - N_1$, $N_0$ also has negative binomial distribution - all you need to do is to replace $q$ with $p$. But still I don't know how to calculate this expected value.

Comment: Multiple errors: 1) You should have specified the range of $n=0,1,2,\dotsc$ 2) For the def of $N_1$ you forgot to specify that $N_1=0 \text{~if~}N=0$ 3) in the mgf of $N$ the exponent is 2 not $n$!